# Smooth formula curves in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to plot a formula in highcharts, for example y = a*x + b*x^2 + cx^3. The curve needs to be smooth (not simply calculating some points and rendering a line chart). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts is not really set up as a mathematically formula plotter. You can generate yourself some data using that formula:

```
var xData = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    a = 2,
    b = 3,
    c = 4;
var fullData = [];
xData.forEach(function (entry) {
    var x = entry;
    var y = a * x + b * (x * x) + c * (x * x * x);
    fullData.push([x, y]);
});
```

Then you can assign `fullData` to your chart:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: fullData
    }]
});
```

To make this chart more smooth you would, of course, increase the resolution of your `x` values.